# ffmpeg not giving output files in desired segmented time

Tags: ffmpeg

I am capturing my screen and saving it locally with segment time as 1 sec.Here is the ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -r 10 -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -map 0 -codec:v libvpx -minrate 6M -maxrate 6M -b:v 6M -f segment -flags -global_header -segment_format webm -segment_time 1 -preset ultrafast segment%03d.webmm
```

The segmented videos are having a duration of 5 sec contrary to the segment time of 1s.

Comment: Your keyframes aren't 1 s apart. Add `-g 1` as a first try.

Comment: Yeah,it worked.Thanks.